# Delete from multiple tables, if has

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables which name users and images in mysql.

users has : id , name, password

images has : id, kid, imagePath

kid = id.

When the admin delete user in users, i want to delete images too, if has.

my sql statement is :

```
"DELETE FROM users u LEFT JOIN images i ON i.kid = u.id WHERE u.id = '{$id}'";
```

This statement returns false. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete from two tables, try this syntax:

```
DELETE u, i
    FROM users u LEFT JOIN
         images i
         ON i.kid = u.id
    WHERE u.id = '{$id}';
```